# What version of EntityFramework's out of band components should be used with .NET 4?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

For deployment reasons, my development team is currently stuck with .NET 4.

However I would like to use the out-of-band `EntityFramework.dll` library (in order to use the `DbContext` API), but I have not been able to find any information regarding whether `EntityFramework.dll` v5 only targets .NET 4.5 or if it can work (albeit with reduced performance and features) on .NET 4.0.

In a nutshell: Can I use `EntityFramework.dll` 5 with .NET 4.0? Or should I use `EntityFramework.dll` 4.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NuGet EntityFramework 5 package contains both Entity Framework 5.0 and Entity Framework 4.4 DLLs. If you include it in a .NET 4 project, you'll get the 4.4 version. If you include it in a .NET 4.5 project, you'll get the 5.0 version. As you suspected, 4.4 lacks some features that did make it into 5.0. You cannot use the 5.0 version in a .NET 4 project, but the 4.4 version will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework 5 (the nuget package) works fine with .NET 4.  There are certain new features (spatial types, auto-query compilation) which require .NET 4.5, but you are fine for 90% of EF development.